# Speed up a C++ code implementing numerical integration

Tags: c++11, numerical-methods

I have this C++ code that implements a rectangular numerical integration

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

float pdf(float u){
     return (1/(pow(1+u, 2)));
}

float cdf(float u){
      return (1 - 1/(u+1));
}
// The main function that implements the numerical integration, 
//and it is a recursive function
float integ(float h, int k, float du){
      float res = 0;
      if (k == 1){
         res =  cdf(h);
      }else{
         float u = 0;
    while (u < h){
        res += integ(h - u, k - 1, du)*pdf(u)*du;
        u += du;
    }
}
     return res;
}
int main(){
    float du = 0.0001;
    int K = 3;
    float gamma[4] = {0.31622777, 0.79432823, 
                1.99526231, 5.01187234};
    int G = 50;
    int Q = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        if ((G-Q*(K-1)) > 0){
            float gammath = (gamma[i]/Q)*(G-Q*(K-1));
            cout<<1-integ(gammath, K, du)<< endl;
    }

 }

    return 0;
}
```

I am facing a speed problem, although I switched to C++ from Python and MATLAB, because C++ is faster. The problem is that I need a small step size *du* to get an  accurate evaluation of the integration.

Basically, I want to evaluate the integral at 4 different points defined by gammath, which is a function of other defined parameters.

Is there anyway I can speed up this program? I already have 25x+ speed factor over the same code in Python, but still the code takes too long (I ran it all night, and it wasn't finished in the morning). And this is only for K=3, and G=50. In other cases I want to test K = 10, and G = 100 or 300.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com might be a better fit for this question.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that you have `(G-Q*(K-1))` in a loop, and two times in each iteration of the loop. Taking it out of the loop might help, not sure how much.

Comment: Replace `pow(u, 2)` by `(u*u)`.

Comment: @RSahu Right, (G-Q*(K-1) must be evaluated once, but I don't think this would speed up my code significantly. I think I need some algorithmic changes in my code that gives me maybe another 25x speed up.

Comment: Better suited for [codereview.se] instead, if you have working code you're just looking to optimize.

Comment: @KenWhite OK, thanks.

Comment: does this baby ever converge? i'm getting `-inf` as first output. takes ages. is this tested? And there is a typo. It does not compile as is.

Comment: @KavehVahedipour Sorry, the argument in the pdf function should be pow(1+u, 2). I will edit it.

Comment: I'll try my best later. But for now could you please explain, why you would want to do the integration yourself? Have you have had a look at `CVODE`?

Comment: @KavehVahedipour What is CVODE? Basically, I want to do the integration myself because it doesn't have a closed-form  solution, and the built-in functions in MATLAB, for example, to do the numerical integrations, don't support K-nested integrals, where K is an arbitrary integer, which is the case in my problem.

Comment: https://computation.llnl.gov/projects/sundials/cvode. but good point i agree. hmm. interesting problem. let's see what i can squeeze out.

Comment: You could look at multi-threading, but again that will be another linear speed-up - though a 64 core machine has to guive some speedup. Each thread should run for a relatively large child tree as there is overhead in kicking off threads.

Comment: @GemTaylor you cannot multi-thread a nested integral. It's a feedback loop.

Comment: I will have to beleive you, but each call to `integ(h - u, k - 1, du)*pdf(u)*du;` looks completely independent to me?

Comment: @GemTaylor Actually, `integ(gammath, K, du)` is independent for each value of `gammath` in the `for` loop in the `main` function, but for a given `gammath`, `nteg(h - u, k - 1, du)*pdf(u)*du;` they are interdependent.

Comment: Still don't see it in the code as presented, not knowing/caring what algorithm it actually implements: all inputs are by value, the only return is accumulated, and there are no globals, but perhaps this is where is scope for an optimisation/ value reuse for a particular h in k=2 level of recursion? In k=3, as u increases to h, k=2 will have less work to do, and it seems to me some of the inputs to k=3 will be the same on some recursion paths.

Comment: Since you [cross posted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/200289/implementing-numerical-integration) this on [codereview.se] you [should delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) this question.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm It wasn't my intention to cross post this. After I posted it here, some people suggested to post it there, because it fits better there. Deleting an answered question makes me liable to potentially getting my account blocked. How can I delete this post without being potentially blocked?

Comment: @BlackMath The use of recursion is usually not conducive to high performance. However, the long run-time suggests the code wasn't compiled with optimizations turned on. On my six year old computer (Xeon CPU E3-1270 V2 @ 3.5 GHz, Win 7 Professional) with five year old Intel compiler version 13.1.3.198, compiled with `icl /Ox /QxHOST /fp:strict`, using the code exactly as posted, run-time was 90 minutes, producing the following output: 0.418665, 0.183092, 0.0709447, 0.0380834

Comment: 90 mins is pretty good actually. The code on my machine intel i5 @2.5 GHz with 6 GB of RAM ran for more than 12 hours, and it didn't finish. How to optimize the compilation process?

Comment: @BlackMath Read your compiler's documentation. `-O3` is usually a good start (I used `/Ox` which is commonly used by compilers on Windows to turn on "all optimizations"). Also make sure you instruct the compiler to take full advantage of your processor's architecture. On compilers for Linux that is often an `-march=` setting or similar. For my compiler on Windows I use `/QxHOST`, meaning "use all architectures features available on the CPU used for compiling the code", which is appropriate when compiling and running on the same machine.

Comment: @njuffa Sorry, I am a bit unfamiliar with the whole process. I use CodeLite IDE, and I don't have control of the options. Do you run the program on the command line? What compiler do you use, and what is your command to run the file (say the name of the file is test.cpp and located on the desktop)?

Comment: If I am right, the triple integral has a simple analytical form. Using it would bring the computation time under the microsecond.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Have you derived it? I tried, and according to my derivations there is no closed-form solution for an arbitrary integer K. May be for K=2 and 3, but I need an implementation for a general K.

Comment: If I am right, the initial integrand is a power -2, that generates -1 then log and you can continue with form P(x) log (x) + Q(x) where P, Q are polynomials.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What do mean by the "initial integrand"? For an arbitrary K, the integrand is in the form of (1-1/(1+gamma-uk-....-u2))(1+u2)^-2*...*(1+uK)^-2. If you are interested (and I am surly interested to hear your intake on this), I can open a topic about this on StackExchange Mathematics. A closed-form solution is a much more desired result.

Comment: @YvesDaoust See [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/200525/implementing-numerical-integration-in-python) for the mathematical formulation, where FU(u) = 1-1/(1+u) and fU(u) = 1/(1+u)^2.

Answer (score 1):

What is behind your computation is that you take the K-fold convolution power of the `pdf` function and then integrate that power from `0` to `h`. As you use Riemann sums for integration, it means that you treat the pdf as a step function with steps of width `du`. In that case, the values of the convolution power can be computed as the coefficients in the power of a (truncated) power series/generating function

```
p(z)=pdf(0)+pdf(du)*z+pdf(2*du)*z^2+...+pdf(n*du)*z^n
```

where `n*du>h`. You can now compute this power via FFT based algorithms. A more basic variant uses that if `q(z)=p(z)^K  mod z^(n+1)` then

```
p(z)*q'(z) = K*q(z)*p'(z)  mod z^n
```

so that the coefficients of `q` can be computed via convolution sums from the coefficients `p[j]=pdf(j*du)` of `p`. Comparing the terms for the power `z^(m-1)` in the above formula gives on the coefficient level

```
sum  p[m-j]*j*q[j] = K * sum  q[j]*(m-j)*p[m-j],    j=0..m
```

or solved for the new coefficient `q[m]` when the previous coefficients `q[0],...,q[m-1]` are already computed:

```
q[m] = 1/(m*p[0]) * sum  (K*(m-j)-j)*p[m-j]*q[j],    j=0..m-1
```

In code that gives

```
q[0] = pow(p[0], K);
for(m=1; m<=n; m++) {
    q[m]=0;
        for(j=0; j<m; j++) { q[m] += (K*(m-j)-j)*p[m-j]*q[j]; }
    q[m] /= m*p[0];
}
```

and then sum up for the result,

```
res = q[0]; 
for(j=1; j*du < h; j++) { res += q[j]; }
res *= pow(du, K);
```

Comment: But in my problem it is not one-dimensional integral, but rather K-dimensional integral, and recursion is necessary because each dimension depends on the value of the integral of the previous dimensions. I don't see the parameter K in the above code.

Comment: Then you should probably write it down that you want to integrate `pdf(u[1])*...*pdf(u_[n])` over the domain `u[k]>=0`, `u[1]+...+u[k]<=h`.

Comment: Sorry about any confusion, but all I wanted is to speed up the program. I didn't know what I actually want to do is important. Maybe I was wrong. Please refere to [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/200289/implementing-numerical-integration) for more details.